# lpr -o page-ranges=1 is still printing all three pages

Tags: linux, cups, lpr

I need to make lpr print just the first page of my document, however it continues to print everything.  Itried these commands:

```
lpr -P <myprinter> -o page-ranges=1 <myfile>
lp -d <myprinter> -o page-ranges=1 <myfile>
lp -d <myprinter> P 1 <myfile>
```

Comment: Which version of CUPS?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the CUPS version. To the googlers of the future:

Yes, the `-o page-ranges=2` should work.

The probable reason behind your problem is that there are previous projects left in your queue. You can check this in the CUPS administration panel on http://localhost:631 . Go to the printer managing and delete all of the tasks there is yet in the printer queue.

And so, you won. Problem solved. Page-ranges work. We are happy. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Appears it would be: lp -p 1

(plus whatever else you'll need to pass to lp to get it to print what you want to print).

http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ulp.htm

Comment: It is probably for an ancient version of the cups, or even not for a cups printing system version. In the current cups, printing happens with the `lpr` command and not with `lp`, and the `-p` flag has different meaning.